# Laravel URL rewrite Error

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5

Actually I am deploying my laravel 5 Application on Client Server.
My client create space for me in such type of path.

```
var/www/html/abcproject
```

Now I have uploaded my all laravel 5 file on abcproject directory.

My issue is that , my home page is working fine but my internal pages
are giving Not Found Error.

Suppose when I try to logged in, throwing this error.

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL `/abcproject/login` was not found on this server.

How to resolve that error?

Comment: Have you pointed project to `public` directory?

Answer (score 1):

You need to point the webroot to `var/www/html/abcproject/public`